# Difference of two identical cells returning 0 within parenthesis

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, cell-formatting, decimal-precision

Newbie to spreadsheets. Difference of two identical cells is returning a value of zero within parenthesis. The exact same operation elsewhere returns just a simple dash.  All cells throughout the spreadsheet are formatted as number>accounting.

I assumed the minuend is less than the subtrahend. I can see the cell with difference showing some non-zero numbers after eleven zeroes, if I format it to whatever arbitrary decimal places. I expected to see the minuend and the subtrahend to follow a similar pattern. But they're all zeroes after the two non-zero numbers, post decimal.

| Subtrahend | Minuend | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12 | - |
| 12068.720000000000000000000000000 | 12068.720000000000000000000000000 | -00000.000000000001818989403545860 |

And then it's all zeroes after that.

What could be causing this issue?

I've tried checking the source data. The values being subtracted are both of them, sum of other cells. I checked the source cells and they're all normal values input manually with two decimal digits formatted as number>accounting.

Clearly there are 15 non-zero digits after the decimal which is the Google Sheets limit. But the two numbers undergoing subtraction don't have any.

Feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue could not be easily replicated. A quick workaround is C1  `=IF(ABS(A1-B1) < 0.0000000001, 0, A1-B1)`

Comment: Related question: [What data types does Google Sheets support?](What data types does Google Sheets support?)